# Unzipper.EXE what is this?

Tags: windows

Has anyone heard of this application and have any idea of its safety?

Edit: One of our customers has a Microsoft error reporting popping up every few seconds with a yes or no dialog. Reporting it does not stop the popup from continuing to appear.

Comment: Impossible to accurately answer without more information. Why are you asking? Where did you find the file? If you right-click and go to properties, does the executable have a company name and other metadata embedded in it?

Comment: You're unlikely to ever find out this way: "Unzipper.EXE" is an incredibly generic filename and it may have been renamed from its original name. Try looking at strings inside the executable to locate a Vendor or Version I. And please don't cross-post.

Comment: don't crosspost your questions!

Comment: If it is legit and someone knows the file could be answered after you know the name of the program and the MD5 hash from the Unzipper.EXE

Comment: @ Ivo: I was unaware that the stack exchange sites had the ability to migrate a question. I apologize that the question ended up here three times to to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on the file name, [the Internet seems not to think so](http://www.threatexpert.com/files/unzipper.exe.html). Of course, an executable can be named anything, perhaps it's something else called Unzipper.exe just to sound innocuous.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link on some forums for IMAGE Information Systems Ltd. one of the site admins posted a link to download a file called unzipper.exe in response to a question about K-pacs (presumably the forum owners software). Not sure if this is the same one but if you start the download you can clearly see that the file name is unzipper.exe. [Here](http://forum.image-systems.biz/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=560) is a link to the forums, hope it helps.

EDIT: I downloaded it into a VM and it does seem to be legitimate software from K-pacs to merge and unzip DICOM-MAIL files.